# efficient Regex script is to select closest anchor tag in keyword

Tags: regex

I have an html from which I need to select nearest anchor tag has my keyword like

```
<a href="/sample/product.html">foo bar foo bar</a> provides for 
senior citizens, foo bar foo bar.</p>
<div class="row btm-pad product-landing-btn-block">
<div class="col-md-12 link-section"><span><a title="Search for Life 
Product"                                             
href="${firstProductLink}/sample/product-sample.html">Search for 
Product></a></span>
</div>
</div>
```

I have regex like this

```
<a(?:.*)firstProductLink(?:.|\n|\r)*?<\/a>
```

to select closest anchor tag of firstProductLink

```
<a title="Search for Life 
Product"                                             
href="${firstProductLink}/sample/product-sample.html">Search for 
Product></a>
```

Instead, regex selects parent anchor tag

```
<a href="/sample/product.html">foo bar foo bar</a> provides for 
senior citizens, foo bar foo bar.</p>
<div class="row btm-pad product-landing-btn-block">
<div class="col-md-12 link-section"><span><a title="Search for Life 
Product"                                             
href="${firstProductLink}/sample/product-sample.html">Search for 
Product></a>
```

I don't know how to fix it. Link to try https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/197

Answer (score 1):

This regex worked. thanks all.

```
<a(?:(?!<a).)*?firstProductLink(?:.|\n|\r)*?<\/a>
```

Comment: You can increase performance by use of `[^>]*?` instead of the lookahead: [`/<a[^>]*?{firstProductLink.*?<\/a>/s`](https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/198) (and use single line flag for make dot match newlines instead of `(?:.|\n|\r)`.